# sending username and password via soap message

Tags: iphone, xml, http, post

I am referring to this link http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/

i was able to hit a web-service using the above example, the problem which i am facing now is i may want to send the username and password as a part of the soap-xml which i am creating on the iphone. Is that safe to have a soap-xml body to have credentials and set in the post body of an http request ?

Answer (score 1):

You should send this over SSL to ensure that the HTTP traffic is encrypted